# Trace of finitely generated projective module

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, traces

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a $k$-algebra with unit. The trace module is
$$
T(A)=A/[A,A],
$$
where $[A,A]$ is the left $A$-module generated by all elements of the form $ab-ba$ for $a,b\in A$. The natural trace map is the projection $T:A\to T(A)$.
For an $A$-module $P$ one wants to construct a trace map 
$$
Tr_P: End_A(P) \to T(A),
$$
which is $k$-linear and satisfies $Tr_P(uv)=Tr_P(vu)$.
If $P=A^n$ is finite free, one has $End_A(A^n)\cong M_n(A^{op})$ and a natural trace map is
$$
Tr_{A^n}((a_{i,j}))=\sum_jT(a_{j,j}).
$$ 
Now if $P$ if finite projective, there exists $Q$ such that $P\oplus Q\cong A^n$    and so one can define a trace for $P$ by
$$
Tr_P(u)=Tr_{A^n}(u\oplus 0).
$$
My question is, whether this trace map does depend on the choice of $Q$?

Comment: Is the source of $Tr _P$ $End _P$?

Comment: Oh sorry, should have been $End_A ( P )$. I changed it.

Comment: Since the complement of $P$ in $A^n$ is also projective, one can construct endomorphisms of $A^n$ which fit in a commutative square involving $u\oplus 0_Q$ and $u\oplus 0_{Q ^\prime}$.  Does this suffice to show that the trace is unique?

Comment: What does the square look like?

Comment: Actually it is much simpler, we don't really have to bother with the projectivity of $Q$.  You get $P\oplus Q$ on the left $P\oplus Q'$ on the right, vertical maps are $u\oplus 0_Q$ and $u\oplus 0_{Q'}$.  I guess the additivity of the trace suffices to conclude that the trace doesn't depend on the choice of $Q$.

Comment: I still don't see how to get this square?

Comment: with $u\oplus 0$ for vertical arrows, $id_p\oplus 0$ for horizontal arrows.

Comment: There are two different zeros around. If you don't take the horizontal arrow to be the same, it won't prove the independence.

Comment: For two horizontal arrows, both zeros are zero map from $Q$ to $Q'$, so they are same, aren't they?

Comment: Ok, fine, but the horizontal maps are not isomorphisms.

Comment: By the way, $[A,A]$ is not naturally a left $A$-module, so $T(A)$ is just a $k$-module, not an $A$-module.

Comment: Trace is defined for endomorphisms, and we have the additivity, so Tr(hozizontal) + Tr(vertical for Q) = Tr(vertical ofr Q') + Tr(horizontal)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a standard way to define the trace (look up "Hattori-Stallings trace") that agrees with yours, but is clearly independent of choices.

For any (left) $A$-module $P$, there's a natural map 
$$\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,A)\otimes_AP\to\operatorname{End}_A(P),$$
sending $\varphi\otimes y$ to the endomorphism $x\mapsto\varphi(x)y$, which is an isomorphism when $P$ is finitely generated projective. Composing its inverse with the map
$$\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,A)\otimes_AP\to A/[A,A]$$
induced by the evaluation map
$$\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,A)\otimes_kP\to A,$$
gives the trace map 
$$\operatorname{Tr}_P:\operatorname{End}_A(P)\to A/[A,A].$$

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I actually remember having heard the name Hattori-Stallings before, but somehow I didn't follow it up.